# Dynamic user control controls are null on load

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, null

I have a base usercontrol in my ASP.Net app, There are HTML markup within this usercontrol that are set to runat="server" and id's. The problem I am having is when the usercontrol is loaded, the HTML markup is being returned as null

ASP.Net C# code:

```
public partial class webonlinecustombase : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public OnlineSystemPageCustom custompage { get; set; }
    public OnlineSystemPageCustom.OnlineSystemPageHdr.OnlineSystemPageModule custommodule { get; set; }

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string typeName = custommodule.ModuleInternetFile;
        inpagelink.HRef = "#" + custommodule.ModuleName.Replace(" ", "").Replace("/", "");
        modtitle.InnerText = custommodule.ModuleName;
        Type child = Type.GetType(typeName);
        UserControl ctl = Activator.CreateInstance(child) as UserControl;
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            this.modsection.Controls.Add(ctl);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="webonlinecustombase.ascx.cs" Inherits="IPAMIntranet.IPAM_Controls.webtemplatecontrols.webonlinecustombase" %>
<a id="inpagelink" runat="server"></a>
<span id="modtitle" runat="server" style="width:100%;text-align:left">Scientific Overview</span>
<div id="modsection" runat="server" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<p><a href="#top" class="bodylink">Back to Top</a></p>
```

Why is the `inpagelink` and `modtitle` being returned as null?

Comment: shouldn't you be loading the UserControl as Page.LoadControl("...") as UserControl instead of activating its type?

Comment: the webonlinecustombase is being loaded as such, but the control that inherits from it is completely dynamic, so I have no idea which controls are going to be called. Can I still use Page.LoadControl for dynamic controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this happen in web applications (not web sites) when changes are made to the source (especially setting runat=server on items that were not previously runat=server), but you don't switch to the designer view.

The way that I resolve this issue is to switch to design view and dirty a property in one of the fields. This usually causes VS to update the designer code-behind file.

You can double-check this file to ensure the controls have been added. If you check it prior to doing this, you should see that they are missing.

Answer (score -4):

asp.net does'n have span class, so you cant do anything in code behind with it.

use LinkButton or HyperLink instead of

the other solution is to create span or a in code, something like this

```
var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.InnerHtml = "From<br/>Date";
span.Attributes["class"] = "blue";
placeholder.Controls.Add(span);
```

hope I helped :))

Comment: the fact that you cant do anything in code behind with a span or div. That is completely false. you can easily work with those HTML tags in code behind if they are hard-coded into the HTML markup, as long as you have an ID and runat="server"

Comment: ups my bad, i thought that you cant do anything from code behind beacuse there is not explicity defined span class, but when you call it from code behind span is HtmlGenericControl class...sorry